# Why is POST request with pool.query only works intermittently when using :id in the middle of URL?

Tags: sql, reactjs, postgresql, express, post

I wasn't quite sure how to phrase this question so feel free to make corrections to improve it as desired.

My goal is to make an HTTP POST that will create comments for a post and add the comment to the database comments table. I believe this necessitates doing an INSERT as well as a JOIN to add the specific POST id to the comment.

This is my first time including two requests in one query so I am unsure if this is correct. I had read about using a UNION but haven't been able to figure out the correct syntax as none of the examples included quotes '' around their requests.

My post route:

```
router.post(`/posts/:id/comments`, (request, response, next) => {
  const { id } = request.params; // tried with and without brackets {}
  const { comment_body } = request.body;

  // Testing for correct params
  console.log(id);
  console.log(comment_body);
  
  pool.query(
    'INSERT INTO comments(comment_body) VALUES($1)', 
    [post_id, comment_body],
    'SELECT * FROM comments JOIN posts ON posts.post_id = commments.post_id',
    (err, res) => {
      if (err) return next(err);

      
    }
  );
});
```

What is strange is that this worked twice then stopped working. There are two entries in the comments table but any further posts don't do anything. This only worked from the comments form and not yet in Postman

This worked in two separate tests. When using brackets around the id, the post was created in the table but no post_id was joined on this table:

```
 const { id } = request.params;
```

If I didn't use the brackets, the post_id was created in the data table:

```
 const id = request.params;
```

Here are my tables:

```
CREATE TABLE posts(
  post_id SERIAL,
  user_id INT,
  post_body CHARACTER varying(20000)
);

CREATE TABLE comments(
  id SERIAL,
  post_id INT,
  user_id INT,
  comment_body CHARACTER varying(20000)
);
```

Originally I had the post_id for comments set as serial but figured if that is supposed to be joined from the posts.post_id, it would probably need to be INT.

Thanks much for any direction.

Comment: `'INSERT INTO comments(comment_body) VALUES($1)'` you are providing `[post_id, comment_body]` as values, but only inserting one value.  Probably you want something like `'INSERT INTO comments(post_id, comment_body) VALUES($1, $2)'`.

Comment: Thank you, yes I had tried to remove post_id from within the brackets and for whatever reason it returned a Proxy error. However, you idea did work for me. Instead of doing the join (which wasn't working), I removed that request altogether. Then I did as you suggested and just added the post_id in the initial insert. I had not though about importing parameters without using a join.

Answer (score 0):

I managed to solve this with the following:

```
router.post(`/posts/:id/comments`,  async (request, response, next) => {
  
  try {

    const { id } = request.params; 
    const { comment_body } = request.body;
    
    await pool.query
      ('INSERT INTO comments(post_id, comment_body) VALUES($1, $2)', 
      [id, comment_body]);

  } catch(error) {

    console.log(error.message)
      
    }    
      
  
});
```

Rather than using the JOIN, I just included the posts ID parameter in the original INSERT and imported it that way. I had initially thought I had to do it as a join but couldn't get a second SQL request to work. Thanks to snakecharmerb for the idea.

I also added async/await.